# Dropdownlist.selecteditem.value = null

Tags: c#

I have stored procedure with 12 parameters. The parameters could be null. I also have 12 drop-down lists. Drop downlists values are pased to the sp. I would like to pass null values from drop down lists into the procedure when dropdownlist.selecteditem.value = null. I tried below assignement:

```
int typeid = (Convert.ToInt16(ddlType.SelectedValue.ToString())) == null ? DBNull.Value : (int)(Convert.ToInt16(ddlType.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

but I got error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'int'

Your help will be fully appreciated.

Comment: Well the error message exactly tells you what is wrong. You cannot assign DBNull to your int variable as DBNull cannot be converted to int.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? your `typeid` is `int` but you still want a possible value `DBNull.Value` as its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `DBNull.Value` can't be assigned to an `int`. One option you do have would be to do something like this:

```
int typeid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlType.SelectedValue) ?
    default(int) :
    Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
```

another option would be to use `int?`:

```
int? typeid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlType.SelectedValue) ?
    (int?)null :
    (int?)Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
```

and there are a lot of other options. But if you're trying to get the value to an `int` and **know** later if there was something selected, these two options are pretty straight forward. In the first case you'd be able to infer that by comparing it later to `default(int)` to see if it was `null` earlier. In the second case it's even more straight forward because you can just say `typeid.HasValue` to see if it's `null` or not.

Now, I took off the `ToString()` calls because they'll fail if `SelectedValue` is `null`. However, if this is a Windows Forms application instead of a Web Forms application (which is what I inferred) then you'll want to convert that value to a string like this:

```
var val = Convert.ToString(ddlType.SelectedValue);
int? typeid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) ?
    (int?)null :
    (int?)Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
```

because `Convert.ToString` will return an empty string if the value is `null`.

Comment: Thanks neoistheone. This worked to me: int? typeid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlType.SelectedValue) ?
    (int?)null :
    (int?)Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);

Answer (score 1):

declare the variable as `int? typeID`

This wil accept integers along with nulls

Here, the above declaration indicates it is nullable

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int typeid = (Convert.ToInt16(ddlType.SelectedValue.ToString())) == null ? (object)DBNull.Value: (int)(Convert.ToInt16(ddlType.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not work with nullable ints in the first place?

```
int? typeid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlType.SelectedValue)? null: Convert.ToInt16(ddlType.SelectedValue);
```

typeid will be null if your dropdown has no vallue. If it does, it will hold it.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedValue property of the DropdownList returns a string, so there is no need to do a ToString conversion.

int is not a nullable type, so you cannot convert a null value to an int. Also, int is an int32, not an int16.

```
int? typeId = ddlType.SelectedValue != null : Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue) ? null;
```

Comment: No, the SelectedValue is not of string type at all,  it's of object type, but because he used `Convert.ToInt32()` method, there is no need for ToString()